# What is absolute good and evil?

Tags: ethics

We human beings have sense organs to perceive whatever is around us. But then we say we have the mind to judge. My point is that if we assume, or I should say realize, that human sense organs have limited input output capabilities, how can we so confidently say we can judge right or wrong using our mind?

Do we consider the mind to have unlimited capabilities or is it just arrogance resulting out of our human nature?

Comment: What else would you use, if not your mind?

Comment: Absolute, objective standards, perhaps?

Comment: You might find something interesting in the question & answer I posted, [How could 'objective morality' be known/investigated?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8506/how-could-objective-morality-be-known-investigated/8507)

Comment: Vague, and opiniin based. And not really coherent, between title and post

Comment: We can make what judgements we like. We won't find 'good' or 'evil' 'out there' in the world.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute good - positive effect

Absolute evil - negative effect

Unfortunately, we do not live in a world of absolutes. Study some religions, they are basically training manuals for how to be "good".(I am sure some are not, that statement is not absolute.)

Comment: I have to admit that "positive effect" and "negative effect" don't sound too absolute to me. But your characterization of good and bad itself seems OK.

Comment: Whenever we start asking about ethics, the most common answer is study religions!Why is it so important?And by the way I'm not interested in "how to be good". I want to know what is good and the basis for defining it.

Comment: At the core of most religions you will find pathways to enlightenment. Like a martial artist studies, and gains different belt colors to represent his proficiency. As you study religions you undergo a similar process, no snazzy belts but it will enlighten you.

Comment: How do we define positive and negative then? WHat is postive to the Neo Nazi and what is positive to the Christian may not be the same.

Comment: Break anything down to small enough pieces, and negative and positive will be the same for everyone.

Comment: I don't agree here.Had it been the case,all the religions of the world would agree in order to create something like a 'global' religion with universal values which everyone could follow but that is not the case.The basic point is we never agree on what is good/bad universally.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we consider the mind to have unlimited capabilities or is it just arrogance resulting out of our human nature?

It has something to do with our concrete examples of the absolute. Many philosophers considered "god" as an example of the absolute, Immanuel Kant considered "the moral law within me" as something absolute, and for Plato "ideas" were examples of the absolute. Today, many people still believe that (at least) the (small) natural numbers are something absolute. (Also "love" is today often advertised as ... hmmm, let's say as less relative than many other things.)

If you don't have access to good (and convincing) examples of the absolute, it is difficult to "measure" how relative your normal judgments are. Also, if you are convinced that there is no such thing as the absolute, everything seems to be much more absolute than it really is, relatively speaking.

Comment: Of course but I don't believe in the absolute nature of things so it is even more difficult to perceive anything created by our nervous system(the mind) as absolute.I'm talking about good and bad It is just a process isn't it and you can't but deny that human mind has no absolute judging capabilities.But there is a trouble in this analogy as well .What if the humans are free from this bondage of "perceived"good and evil?There'll be chaos isn't it?

Comment: @VivekJha If you replace "created by our nervous system" with "discovered by our nervous system", "perceived by our nervous system" or "revealed to our nervous system", you might perhaps better understand how it can happen that "we consider the mind to have unlimited capabilities", if our judgement capabilities are not calibrated well enough by good (and convincing) "practical" examples.

Comment: You mean the mind acts like a some kind of measuring instrument?

Comment: @VivekJha No, I just try to answer your question "Do we consider the mind to have unlimited capabilities or is it just arrogance resulting out of our human nature?" If you say something is "created by our nervous system", then of course it's hard to understand why somebody could judge it more absolute than it actually is. But if you realize that people might view their "creations" more as some sort of "revelation" or "discovery", then perhaps its easier to see how they can be wrong without necessarily being arrogant or naive.

Comment: SO then you say that whether it's good or evil it is there, firm and we have limited reach of judgement or I should say perception right?And hence it means that there exists something like absolute good and absolute evil and there is dualism indeed!But I fail to understand this for if the division indeed existed,we'd not be the judges at all..

Comment: @VivekJha Your problem is probably that your actual question is different from what I understood your question to be. You got two answers to your question, one talks about "good and bad" and one talks about "absolute". That's probably what you get here, when you ask "Can someone tell me what is absolute good and evil?" The first part of my answer was "inspired" by Kant's "Critique of Practical Reason", but not worthy of it. The second part is primarily my own opinion with respect to people who are convinced that "everything is relative, nothing is absolute".

Comment: Yeah you're right.I'm not interested in the existing definitions of either good or evil for they are too easy to find .I wanted to inquire about the basis on which we define these values..this will give us the absolute isn't it?But then things get complicated right here itself.

Answer (score 1):

Many philosophers (the moral relativists, for example) argue that there is no such thing as objective morality. So if we take that into account, there cannot be absolute good or evil, for such absolutes would be in subjective view.

Moral realists, on the other hand, would offer that we can have objective morality, which would lead to absolute good or evil. You talk about sense capacity and our ability to utilize it, so I recommend Sam Harris’ “The Moral Landscape” for more information on how we could obtain objective morality.

In the end, I suppose, depends on which camp you reside in: moral relativism or moral realism.